# Rigged dice ( How to define events in order to use the "multiplication rule" ?)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Take $n$ , $n$ - sided rigged dice with the probability of a die landing on the $i$th side being $p_i$ for $ i =1, ..., n$.

Throw $k$ dice ( $k \in [1,n]$), what is the probability that all of the $k$ throws will be different?

I would like to treat this problem as a sequence of events, and then use the relation:

\begin{equation} 
P ( \cap_{l=1}^{m} A_l) = P(A_1) P(A_2|A_1) ... P( A_m | \cap_{l=1}^{m-1} A_l )\tag{1}
\end{equation}

But, I am not quite sure on how to define the events $A_l$ so that the previous relation makes sense.

Even for the simplest case: the "fair" case ( $ p_i = \dfrac{1}{n}) $ , where this becomes a "counting problem" ,the probabilty of getting $k$ different throws being:

$$ P =  \dfrac{\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}}{n^{k}} $$

I am unsure on how to define the events in order to be able to use $(1)$...

Comment: What sort of answer are you hoping for?  The result is inevitably going to be a messy expression in the $\{p_i\}$.

Comment: @lulu  hmm ,I was thinking that $(1)$ would simplify things...

Comment: @lohey Do you know anything about the individual $p_i$'s? For example, if $i \neq j$ then do you have $p_i \neq p_j$?

Comment: I don't see how that helps.  Computationally, just sum over the $\binom nk$ ways to choose $k$ distinct terms from $n$.  Easy to get the probability of each, but the sum is ugly.  I don't see anything better unless you have more information on the individual probabilities.

Comment: @SlipEternal no, there is no restriction , in fact the case where $ p_i = p_j$ for $ i \neq j$ $i,j = 1,...,n-1$,  and $p_n \neq p_i$ ( only one side is rigged , the other sides are fair) I generalized to get the my problem

Comment: If there are no restrictions, then I suspect the answer will be $$\sum_{A \subset [n] \\ |A| = k}k!\prod_{i \in A} p_i$$ or something similar (I have not validated that formula, but I suspect it is correct).

Comment: Hmm, I am mistaken. I am not taking into account cases where $i\neq j, p_i=p_j$.

Comment: @SlipEternal I disagree.  I do not think that your previous comment is mistaken.  In the situation where $i \neq j, p_i = p_j$, you do want to *count it twice*.  So, the algorithm works regardless of whether $p_i$ does or does not equal $p_j$.

Comment: @user2661923 You may be right. I haven't tested the formula to see if it matches simulation.

Comment: @lohey The more I think about it, the more I think the formula above is correct. Does that suffice?

Comment: @SlipEternal yes!, thanks:).  Could you elaborate a bit on the notation, I'm not quite sure what $ A \subset [n]  , |A| = k$ means.

Comment: I will turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[n] = [1,n] \cap \mathbb{N} = \{1,\ldots, n\}$ be the set of integers $1$ through $n$.

For any subset $A \subset [n]$, there exists a mapping between $A$ and a set of rolls of dice where each die rolls a different number. Let's use some examples. If $n=4$ and $A = \{1\}$, this is represented by one die rolling a $1$. If $A = \{1,3\}$, this represents two dice rolling a $1$ and a $3$.

If you are rolling $k \in [n]$ dice, then you only care about $A$ if $|A| = k$. This means the set $A$ contains $k$ distinct values. So, let's look at our example with $A = \{1,3\}$. This set not only represents when we have two dice and the first rolls a $1$ and the second rolls a $3$. It also represents when the first rolls a $3$ and the second rolls a $1$. In other words, this set does not take order into account. But, the probability for either order will be the same since $p_1p_3 = p_3p_1$.

So, for a given subset $A \subset [n], |A| = k$, there are $k!$ different orders. And the probability for any individual order is given by $$\prod_{i \in A} p_i$$

So, the probability over all possible orders is $$k!\prod_{i \in A}p_i$$

And we can sum over all possible subsets:

$$k!\sum_{A \subset [n] \\ |A| = k}\left(\prod_{i \in A}p_i\right)$$

Unless you start grouping together faces with the same probability, it is unlikely there will be a way to simplify this.